# Как называется свойство Ajax - во время ожидания ответа от сервера?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Всем привет, есть такой запрос.

```
$(document).ready(function () {             
            $("#upload_image").imageUpload("upload.php", {
                uploadButtonText: "Button",
                previewImageSize: 150,

                onSuccess: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }

            });
        });
```

Во время успешного выполнения сервер что-то возвращает и вызывается alert. А как называется свойство, когда мы послали запрос, но еще не получили ответ от сервера? Я хочу, чтобы во время этого крутилась gifka, что идет загрузка, подождите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше что-то вроде этого:

```
[html]
<div id="destination">сюда ждем результат, а пока ждем крутится "загрузка"</div>
[/html]

[js] // нужен jquery
var loader = '<img src="loader.gif">';

$('#destination').html(loader);

$.post("test.php", { 
    name: "John", 
    time: "2pm" 
}, function(data) {

    $('#destination').html(data);

});
[/js]
```

Comment: Псс, парень - не хочешь немного imageUpload'ера?  
У него-то есть этот плагин, нельзя его просто вырезать.

Comment: Молчу, Доктор, согласен :) Только давайте не будем псыкать друг на друга. Взрослые же люди.

Comment: Это мэм, я просто прикол заюзал, для этого никакой возраст не помеха :)

Comment: Хех, еще один попался на серьезность :) Все в норме
(офтопим, кстати)

Comment: @densmith, кто бы говорил =)  
И правда, оффтоп никто не любит, хотя надо было бы тут чат сделать ИМХО.

Answer (score 2):

Это сторонний плагин, обработчик может быть любой, см. документацию к нему.
В стандартной реализации ajax от jQuery обработчик называется `beforeSend()`, см. [документацию.](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-запрос)